# Create new site collection in existing web application with different existing content DB

Tags: site-collection, content-database

I have a SharePoint 2010 root level site collection SC1 in web application WEBAPP1. I want to create copy of that site collection in same web application WEBAPP1. Apart from Import/Export, Restore/Backup options, will following approach work? If yes , how?

- I took backup of content database of web application.
- Restored database with different name
- Mounted Content database to this WEBAPP1 by assigning new ID to DB
- Created new site collection by using this newly mounted DB

Site collection gets created successfully but content does not appear.

Please guide if i can achieve desired functionality by using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

when you restore the existing DB even with new ID/GUID but still site collection url will be same, so in that case it will not work.

**For Sp 2010**
You have to go with either backup and restore to new database or export & import method.

**For Sp 2013**
If you want to copy of existing site then you can use [copy-spsite](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=372) command.

```
Copy-SPSite http://contoso/sites/OldTeam -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content -TargetUrl http://contoso/sites/NewTeam
```

You have to create new Content DB then run above command.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I missed to mention i am using SharePoint 2010. So Copy-SPSite command will not work.This is an excellent option. Wish this existed in 2010 !

Comment: then your best bet is backup and restore to new database.